# How do I expect a message whose argument is any instance of a class in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How do I write a message expectation that expects to be called with any instance of a class? I'd like to do something like this:

```
@controller.should_receive(:sign_in_and_redirect).with(kind_of? User)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@controller.should_receive(:sign_in_and_redirect).with(an_instance_of(User))`

See the "Argument matchers" section of the [Relish documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations) for more details. I linked to the RSpec 2.13 docs, but there should be a select box that allows you to change the document version if you need to.

**Update:**
In the [RSpec 3.2 docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments), they say to use `instance_of`.

Comment: `expected: (#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x007fcb1ae80e08 @klass=User(id: integer ...)>)
got: (:user, #<User id: nil ...>)`

Comment: Hmm, should have worked according to the docs. Must be a bug or something wrong with my code.

Comment: It looks like someone else got something similar: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/202. What version of RSpec and Rails are you using?

Comment: RSpec 2.14.7 / Rails 4.0.0.

Comment: This is hackey, but you *could* subclass your controller for this one test, and override the `sign_in_and_redirect` method. In the new version of the method, you could raise an exception if an instance of `User` was not passed in. You'd need to figure out a way to invoke the new controller. This would obscure the clarity of the test, but it would make sure the app behaved as expected.

Comment: If you did that, your test would expect that invoking the `sign_in_and_redirect` method did not raise an error. I'm not a fan of this, but it may be a last-resort if nothing else works. Just put a comment above your spec describing why you did what you did.

Comment: Thanks, I´m going to see if I can "stub in" a instance and test that it returns that instance.